# starting and stopping apache flume agents on a cluster

Tags: java, linux, cluster-computing, flume

I want to monitor apache flume instances installing on separate nodes on a cluster. Like starting a flume instance when it was not running, stop it when needed. And especially my java application just installs on a particular node of a cluster.

I did research but could not find the proper results.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cron to run a python script regularly, and using the Cloudera Manager Python API (https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/docs/python-client/#inspecting-a-service) you can perform these kinds of operations. I've written this script for you:

```
from cm_api.api_client import ApiResource

CM_HOST = "ENTER_HOST"
CM_USER = "ENTER_USR_NAME"
CM_PASSWD = "ENTER_PASSWD"

DATA_CLUSTER = "ENTER_CLUSTER"
SERVICE_LIST=[         #Find out service names by looking in CM > Service > Charts Library > Charts Builder
"flume19",
"flume20",
"flume21",
etc,
etc,
]

api = ApiResource(CM_HOST, version=5, username=CM_USER, password=CM_PASSWD, use_tls=True)
cluster = api.get_cluster(DATA_CLUSTER)
for i in range (len(SERVICE_LIST)):
        service = cluster.get_service(SERVICE_LIST[i])
        for role in service.get_all_roles():
                if service.roleState = "STOPPED":
                    service.restart_roles(role.name)[0]
```

This checks to see if the role state is stopped and starts it again if so. However, if you refer to the link above, there is much more you can do with the API. This seems a sensible starting place though.

You're question wasn't especially clear, so forgive me if this is not the information you were after!

Thanks.